# Need Batch File to Read the Host IPV4 and IPV6 address

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, ip-address

I'm working on a batch file and I am completely lost at this part.
I need to get the batch file to read the computer's IPV4 and IPV6 address, then write it down in a text document.
If it's impossible in batch is there a chance a VBscript can do it?
My only idea so far has been to set the IPV4 and IPV6 address as a variable, then echo the variable to a text document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and post what did you tried as code until now !

Comment: @Hackoo I haven't tried anything yet I was completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
@Echo off
Title Get the Local IPv4 adress
Color 0A & Mode con cols=50 lines=3
echo( 
For /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('arp -a ^|findstr /i "Interface"') do (set IP=%%a)
Echo       The Local IPv4 adress is : %IP%
pause>nul
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Could you please explain how this works? You don't have to do it, of course, but it would benefit me in the future most likely.

Comment: @EliR You can also check another [methods here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671030/how-to-grab-ipv4-variable-in-cmd-and-ping-in-new-cmd-window?answertab=active#tab-top)